# JFreeChart: XYAreaRenderer2 with StandardXYItemLabelGenerator

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart

I am trying to use a `StandardXYItemLabelGenerator` with an `XYAreaRenderer2` renderer, but nothing is showing up. If is use the same code with an `XYLineAndShapeRenderer` I correctly see the labels on the chart. How can I see these labels on the `XYAreaChart`?

```
 // create the chart...
        final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYAreaChart(
                header_label, // chart title
                x_label, // x axis label
                y_label, // y axis lsabel
                dataset, // data
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
                includeLegend, // include legend
                true, // tooltips
                false // urls
                );

        // NOW DO SOME OPTIONAL CUSTOMIZATION OF THE CHART...
        chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);

        // get a reference to the plot for further customization...
        final XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
        plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.lightGray);
        plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.white); // X Axis is Domain
        plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.white);  // Y Axis is Range

        // Allow lines and shapes to be visible
        renderer1 = new XYAreaRenderer();

        // Set the tooltip generator
        renderer1.setBaseToolTipGenerator(toolTipGenerator);

        NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
//        renderer1.setBaseItemLabelGenerator(new StandardXYItemLabelGenerator("{0} {1} {2}", NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(), NumberFormat.getNumberInstance()));
        renderer1.setBaseItemLabelGenerator(new StandardXYItemLabelGenerator("test  {0} {1} {2}", NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(), NumberFormat.getNumberInstance()));

        renderer1.setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true);

        plot.setRenderer(renderer1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike `XYLineAndShapeRenderer`, neither `XYAreaRenderer` nor `XYAreaRenderer2` invokes the abstract parent's `drawItemLabel()`. In effect, labels are not supported, but tool tips are, as suggested below.

```
XYAreaRenderer2 renderer = new XYAreaRenderer2(
    new StandardXYToolTipGenerator("test: {0} {1} {2}",
    NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(),
    NumberFormat.getNumberInstance()), null);
plot.setRenderer(renderer);
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I call the method myself or do anything else to get it to display, even in a hack-ish way?

Comment: I've never tried; at a guess, the labels may conflict with the chart's use of `AlphaComposite`.